# How to copy values from data.frames with different length?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to extract specific values from one data.frame to another. The frames have different length but similar names (i.e. `'a'::'z'` and `'a'::'w'`)

```
names <- letters[1:26]

df1 <- data.frame("name" = names[1:20],"value" = rnorm(20, mean = 4, sd = 1))
df2 <- data.frame("name" = names[1:26],"value" = rnorm(26, mean = 4, sd = 1))

df2$value2 <- df1[df2$name %in% df1$name,]$value
```

The last line above does not work but produces the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "value2", value = c(4.21005563122984,  : 
  replacement has 20 rows, data has 24
```

Any suggestions how I produce something like this:

```
  name    value   value2
1    a 4.210056 5.918197
2    b 3.203976 4.485109
3    c 4.290336 4.210056
......
25   y 5.918197 NA
26   z 3.861640 NA
```

Comment: Use either `merge` or `match`  For me the second line also gives the same error `df2 <- data.frame("name" = names[1:26],"value" = rnorm(24, mean = 4, sd = 1))`

Comment: as @akrun mentioned, match or merge like: `df2$value2 <- df1$value[match(df2$name, df1$name)]`

Comment: thank you, @din. match does the trick

Comment: @akrun I forgot to change the other value in line 2. Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

df2$value2[df2$name %in% df1$name] <- df1$value